# How can I find records in a subquery result where an item has a result which is false and has no results which are true?

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I'm pretty deep into a combination of joins and subqueries which have ended up having a query result which looks like this: I'm not dealing with marbles at all, but I guess a way of explaining this would be to imagine a bag with blue and red marbles. Bag 1 contains both blue and red, (hence a result for true and false), Bag 2 also the same. Bag 3 only only contains blue marbles and no red ones, so there is only one entry which is true. And bag 4 contains only red ones so the value is false.

What I'm trying to do is select all the IDs where they don't have a 'true' value. So in this case below, IDs 1,2 and 3 all have a row which has the value 'true', whereas IDs 4 and 5 only contains false(s) and no trues. So I want the query to return ID 4 and 5. These results are grouped by their IDs so I've been trying different HAVING clauses, trying to count where COUNT of trues = 0 for a specific idea but haven't had any success.

Input: this table (which is a result of a bigger query)

```
| ID | hasBlueMarbles   | 
| -- | ------- |
| 1  | true    |
| 1  | false   |
| 2  | true    |
| 2  | false   |
| 3  | true    |
| 4  | false   |
| 5  | false   |
| 5  | false   |
```

expected output: IDs which only have a record for the value 'false' and not 'true'

```
| ID | 
| -- |
| 4  |
| 5  |
```

This is probably quite a weird dataset to have in the first place, probably meaning I did something quite wrong with my initial queries that got me here. If needed I can add the main query but it may be a little confusing out of context. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. BOOL_OR()**

The function you are looking for is `BOOL_OR()`.

[Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_BOOL_OR.html) explains as:

> If any value in a set is true, the BOOL_OR function returns true (t). If no value in a set is true, the function returns false (f).

Here goes:

```
SELECT ID, 
       BOOL_OR(hasBlueMarbles) AS HasBlueMarbles
FROM table
GROUP BY ID
HAVING BOOL_OR(hasBlueMarbles) = FALSE
```

**2. MAX()**

Or you can simply use `MAX()` function to take the biggest of booleans and filter out the result.

```
SELECT ID, 
       MAX(hasBlueMarbles) AS HasBlueMarbles
FROM table
GROUP BY ID
HAVING MAX(hasBlueMarbles) = 0
```

Comment: Perfect! I've never heard of BOOL_OR or using MAX for this but as you said it is indeed the function that I was looking for. Thank you!